# Sumo Simulator, VEINS

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

need your help
I am new to SUMO. I am using SUMO OMNET++, VEINS and Prext. How to know the boundary of the road on which vehicle moves, is there any function defined which gives the road boundaries.
How to send multiple messages from the same vehicle at given timestamp.??

I am able to manipulate the Vehicle position by adding some random values to it, but the problem is that , the new modified Vehicle position comes out of the road (lane).

Please help this.

Regards
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why but I feel you are trying to broadcast the safety message (BSMs) of vehicles with falsified locations (of course to confuse the tracker) but it is against the requirements of road-safety, you will confuse other vehicles (except if you have a mechanism to filter the wrong locations by the other legitimate vehicles).

Anyways, I do not know such a function that returns the road's extremities, but, how about creating a grid model? this why you can determine if a point is inside the road or not (it is up to you to create the function for that, it will be feasible at least and accurate to some extent).